Can't access database in another region
I have a database in us-east-1 region which does not allow public access. I have ecs tasks in us-west-1 region in a private subnet. How can I allow the security group of the ecs in us-west-1 access the database in us-east-1 region since the database is not publicly accessible.
I tried using vpc peering connection but this did not work because the cidr ranges of the vpcs in us-east-1 and us-west-1 overlap. What is the best way to allow this traffic?

You can use AWS PrivateLink and NLB to get access to your database from another AWS Region. You will pay for traffic on your AWS PrivateLink.

To solve the problem of overlapping CIDR ranges, you can use AWS transit gateway with Network Address Translation (NAT).
AWS Transit Gateway (TGW) acts as a hub that connects your VPCs and on-premises networks through a central gateway. When you have overlapping CIDR ranges, you can use NAT to translate IP addresses, allowing communication between VPCs without IP conflicts.
For this you have to create transit gateway in each region then after attach the VPCs to the respective transit gateway. And for translating overlapping CIDR blocks to non-overlapping IP ranges, you could use NAT gateway.
And the answer to your second question would be, is route traffic from us-west-1 to the database in us-east-1 using translated IP addresses.

you can use HA proxy server in database region
and using that you can route application request to HA proxy and HA proxy will route request to Database server.
Install HA proxy in ubuntu(database region)
sudo apt update
sudo apt install haproxy -y
sudo nano /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
listen port_3306
bind :3306

mode tcp

option tcplog

server RDS_ENDPOINT:3306

save file
sudo systemctl restart haproxy
sudo systemctl enable haproxy
and In application you need to mention HA proxy public ip instead of RDS_ENDPOINT.
